# How to fix width of every bar column in bar chart.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts

I want to fix column width and when dynamically add new column x-axis scroll add and fix the width of bar column,

But currently the bar chart automatic responsive bar column width, so how can I add fix width with x-axis scroll in bar chart.js

click for this link for

```
 (https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/1872)
```

Comment: please suggest me some right way , how to fix this issue .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i add fix width of bar chart in chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919696/how-can-i-add-fix-width-of-bar-chart-in-chart-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `responsive: false` in your options.

per your jsfiddle:

```
var option = {
  responsive: false,
    scales: {
    ... etc.
```

See here also: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

This will make your chart non-responsive. You will then have to apply your css to allow for horizontal scrolling and some additional javascript to dynamically resize/redraw the chart if you're adding data points dynamically.